# how do i run google voice from vb6

Tags: vb6, google-voice

How do I run Google Voice from Visual Basic 6?

Answer (score 0):

See this brief explanation of the API:

http://posttopic.com/topic/google-voice-add-on-development

and see what you can come up with.